# Number of idempotent endomorphisms of [1,n]

Tags: combinatorics

The question asked was: let $A=\{1,2,...n\}$

how many functions $f:A\mapsto A$ such that $f$ is idempotent? That is, $f \circ f = f$

By considering the possible cardinal of the set of fixed points of such functions, I found that there are $\sum_{k=0}^{n}{{{n}\choose k}\times k^{n-k}}$ such functions.

However, I couldn't find a simpler expression for this sum, either by looking for a recursion formula, or by computing it directly.

Do you have any idea how to simplify it? I have thought about finding another form by double counting the number of functions

Comment: I don't think that there is a simpler form. Tale a look here: https://oeis.org/A000248

Answer (score 1):

Let $S$ be the set of idempotent functions. It is convenient to write $S$ as the disjoint union of $S_i$, where 
$S_i$ is the subset of functions $f$ such that $|Im(f)|=i$. It is clear that

$S=\bigcup_{i\in \{1,\dots ,n\}}S_i$ and $S_i\cap S_j=\emptyset$ if $i\neq j$.

So

$|S|=\sum_{i=1}^n|S_i|$

You can observe that if $f$ is idempotent then $Im(f)=Fix(f)$ because if $x\in Im(f)$ then $x=f(y)$ and so

$f(x)=f\circ f (y)=f(y)=x$

Now we want to determine the cardinality of $S_i$ for each $i\in \{1,\dots, n\}$:

$|S_n|=1$, infact there is only a surjective function $f$ such that $f\circ f=f$. This function is $Id_A$ because $f$ is a bijective map and then

$f=f^{-1}\circ(f\circ f)=f^{-1}\circ f=Id_A$

Let $f\in S_{n-1}$, then $Im(f)$ has cardinality $n-1$. If we suppose that $n\not \in Im(f)$ then $Im(f)=\{1,\dots, n-1\}$, but each point of the image of $f$ is a fixed point, so $f$ fixes the first $n-1$ points, because $Im(f)=\{1,\dots , n-1\}$. Then the number of functions $f$ that have image  $\{1,\dots ,n-1\}$ is $n-1$. So we have

$S_{n-1}=(n-1)*$(number of way to subtract a single point from a set of $n$ points)$=n(n-1)$

We must consider also the case $S_{n-2}$ to get an intuition of what happened. 
Let  be $f\in S_{n-2}$ and we suppose that

$Im(f)=\{1,\dots n-2\}$

In this case that points are fixed points for $f$, so we have only 2 points that can be mapped by $f$ in $(n-2)^2$ different way. So we have

$S_{n-2}=(n-2)^2*$(number of way to subtract $2$ points from a set of $n$ points)$=(n-2)^2\binom{n}{2}$

In general

$S_{n-k}=(n-k)^k\binom{n}{k}$

So

$|S|=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}|S_{n-k}|=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(n-k)^k\binom{n}{k}$

Comment: *subtract* is the correct English form.

Comment: Thanks you very much, I don’t know how to write  very well in English

Comment: That's a good explanation for how to find the result, but it does not give us a better form for the result. As pointed out by another user, it is likely there is no simpler form known

Comment: No, I think there is not a closed form for the problem